# Preparing for Android's future without Flash

Tags: android, flash, html

My app currently uses the OpenYoutubeActivity API to launch the browser and play a youtube video.  I want to make sure that years from now when Flash is no longer seen on Android that this functionality will still work.

My question is this, will Android browsers always be able to play a youtube video whether it's with Flash or HTML5, or is there something I should do to make sure HTML5 is used to play a video?  i.e. "?html5=1" at the end of the url.

Thanks!

Comment: "I want to make sure that years from now" you can't even make sure that Android still exists then. Try getting your app to work correctly on a device that has no flash, that's the best you can do now.

Comment: I am sure google knows about it and will take care of this. Google would enable its browser to play youtube videos before getting ride of flash.

Answer (score 2):

For youtube video, you can open the video in the Youtube app, if not instaled the youtube app, you can open the link youtube in the browser

```
if(isAppInstalled("com.google.android.youtube", getApplicationContext())) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + "WvYsIGYsgJQ"));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity"); 
    startActivity(intent);
}
else {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvYsIGYsgJQ")));
}

public static boolean isAppInstalled(String uri, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```